# How to use Sonatype Nexus with Gradle to proxy repsitories?

Tags: gradle

Say I have Sonatype Nexus running on an internal server, and I would like to use it to proxy repo1.maven.org and other repositories. In Maven I would simply add a `<mirror>` configuration to `settings.xml`. How can I do this with Gradle?

**Update:** I would like to do this without having to hard-code the URL of my Nexus instance into each and every project I have. So I'm looking for an exact replica of the Maven `<mirror>` setting.

The best I could come up with for now is to do something like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "$nexusUrl/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

And then have this in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` on each developer's computer:

```
nexusUrl = https://nexus.company.com
```

However, this looks hacked, and I still have to add the 5 lines to each project. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Init scripts might be the best way to go.  Take a look at this chapter in the [User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

They provide a way for you to inject logic into all of your projects.

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#mavenIvyRepositoriesNoAuth) and [about init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html):

Create a folders and file ending in `.gradle` e.g.: `~/.gradle/init.d/mirror.gradle`.
With content:

```
initscript {
  repositories {
     maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The fragment id in this documentation URL is no longer present- which part of the documentation are you referring to?

Comment: This solution is missing the point! In Maven you can specify a repository in the project pom. On your PC you can override it with your own repository, but this is the choice of the developer, not of the artifact author. How can the artifact author decide which local repo you want to use?

Comment: @BrunoRanschaert The artifact author doesn't decide anything regarding what repo you use to find the artifact. gradle is a build tool. If you build project A, relying on dependency B, the build.gradle file of project A decides where to find the dependency B. The pom of dependency B, if generated by gradle, doesn't contain any repository information. Because, unlike with Maven, the pom is only used to describe the dependencies (and authors, license, etc.) of an artifact. Not to specify how/where to download the dependencies, or how to build the artifact.

Comment: @jb-nizet. You are missing my point. I am a library author, I publish my library to say git with a build.gradle. Now you download the library to make some local modifications (open source) but you want to use your companies repo. You as a library user/modifier should be able to put a proxy in there without having to modify the library source. There are several reasons why you would want to proxy for certain artifacts: eg. you might have modified one of the dependencies, ... (this discussion is another topic).