# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to build a project in Android Studio. The project uses Gradle.

At the time, maven.org is experiencing some problems and I get following errors:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':MyProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyProject:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+.
Required by:
Android:MyProject:unspecified
> Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.5.4/gradle-0.5.4.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

It made me think I don't want to depend on maven.org and internet connection for my builds!

Is there a way I could drop these dependencies and make Android Studio self-sufficient? I would like to be able to build my Android projects even without internet connection and even if maven.org never recover.

EDIT:

If I understand it right, there is a way to setup local Maven repository and then use

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

instead of

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

in `build.gradle` files.

Unfortunately, I am not sure if it's the way and what are downside of this approach.

**UPDATE (December, 2013):**

Android Studio now supports Gradle Offline mode (since [version 0.4.0](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released)). More information can be found in release notes for the Studio.

Comment: The answer is here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio020released

Comment: @g00dy could you please be more specific? I've seen these release notes but not sure how they answer my question.

Comment: @Bobrovski - did you read the Notes at the end?

Comment: I also found a similar logged bug here: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2034

Comment: @g00dy Yes, I did. I am running Android Studio 0.2.2 under Mac OS X (it renders both notes obsolete, I guess).

Comment: It seems repo1.maven.org is down right now.

Comment: @edbond - Well, I'm accessing it ..

Comment: @Bobrovski - I'm still not confident in the usage of the Android IDE ...

Comment: @g00dy yes, it is fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to use maven local repo instead of remote one you need to add jar files to local repository.

Local maven repository is located at

```
~/.m2/repository
```

To compile android projects you need Android Builder library. You can download jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/builder/0.5.4 or compile source code by your own.

To install this library type in your command line:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.android.tools.build \
-DartifactId=builder \
-Dversion=0.5.4 \
-Dfile=builder-0.5.4.jar \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Then in build.gradle file you can use

```
mavenLocal()
```

instead of

```
mavenCentral()
```

Obviously it may turns out that to you need some extra libs in local repo to run Android project, but process of adding different libs is exactly same as above.

Instead of command line adding libraries can be done by e.g. Archiva app.
http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi

Comment: Cool! Did you add also some extra libraries or Android Builder was enough to compile project ?

Comment: I had to install Gradle too.

Answer (score 3):

For now you can swap

```
mavenCentral()
```

to

```
maven { url "http://us.maven.org/maven2/" }
```

in your build.gradle

but for completely offline access you can create your local maven repository on your computer - probably

You can look at: [How to use Sonatype Nexus with Gradle to proxy repsitories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210037/how-to-use-sonatype-nexus-with-gradle-to-proxy-repsitories)

Comment: Thank you, Jacek. But unfortunately, I still can't understand how to make Android Studio self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

please check your internet connectivity

after reading the second part of your question:
 - the stuff gets cached - so you are able to build even without internet connectivity

Comment: was reading your question - just not completely - updated my answer