# How to access company artifact repository from Gradle?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'd like to access my custom-developed Gradle plugins on the company's internal Artifactory instance. I want this for each and every Gradle build happening inside the company. Am I missing something, or the recommended way is really adding this in front of every single Gradle build in every project?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username artifactoryUser
                password artifactoryPassword
            }
            url "http://artifactory.example.com/plugins"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way (like with Maven in `~/.m2/settings.xml`) to specify a default repository somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you can add init scripts:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Found answer here: [How to use Sonatype Nexus with Gradle to proxy repsitories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210037/how-to-use-sonatype-nexus-with-gradle-to-proxy-repsitories)

Comment: Managing every users `~/.gradle/init.gradle` is brittle. Therefore, if you don't want to repeat the information in every build, I'd recommend to ship a custom Gradle distro containing an `init.gradle`. There will likely be a more elegant solution in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I wonder: what form would this elegant solution take?

Comment: For example, there could be a fully qualified "apply plugin" notation that resolves plugins from a predefined plugin repository URL (which your DNS could point to your repository server).