# What is the gradle equivalent of maven repository mirrors?

Tags: maven, gradle

When working with Maven projects, I like to configure a local mirror (e.g. Artifactory) for various 3rd party repositories.  I do this via the `settings.xml` file in my home directory.

I cannot find a similar setting for Gradle - all documentation seems to suggest *adding a new repository*, rather than proxying/mirroring calls to repos which are already defined.  This does not have the same effect.  Is there a simple way to proxy remote Maven or Ivy repositories in Gradle?

Comment: There is a similar question that provides a few suggestions.  The accepted answer is to use init scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210037/how-to-use-sonatype-nexus-with-gradle-to-proxy-repsitories

Comment: @ken I don't like the accepted answer to 13210037 it is too generic to be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

You can define a [custom repository](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:repositories_tutorial) such as:

```js
// build.gradle or settings.gradle
repositories {
  maven {
    url "http://repo1.mycompany.com/maven2"
  }
  maven {
    url "http://repo2.mycompany.com/maven2"
  }
}
```

If you want to share this definition across projects, move it to an [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)

Comment: Thanks!  These suggestions don't seem different from those in the original question...

Comment: @Armand You can use a server such as Artifactory/Nexus that that will be the only repository you use and it will proxy the calls to the external repositories, keeps a company-wide cache, etc.

Comment: It's true!  But the OP is referring to transparently mirroring repositories (e.g. for third-party dependencies), rather than modifying `build.gradle` for every project.

Comment: putting a repositories declaration in a file called `init.gradle` in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory or `GRADLE_HOME/init.d/` would be the Gradle equivalent to using Maven and `settings.xml`. Is this what the OP is referring to?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it could make a suitable answer!  Thanks :-)

Comment: Great. Please note I had already mentioned it in my original answer. Also, if it helps, please mark it as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test at the moment, so I can't really accept an answer (the original question is nearly 3 years old).  I think the answer could be improved by actually detailing _how_ to use init scripts, and removing the irrelevant `build.gradle` config.

Comment: Also "use init scripts" was also mentioned in a comment 2 years ago, so without an example this answer doesn't add much except for the helpful link.

Comment: This [link](https://rahulsom.github.io/blog/2016/gradle-equivalent-of-maven-mirror.html) is also helpful.

Comment: you can add multiple `maven` entries for multiple repos. I have amended the example snippet above.

Answer (score 6):

We have an internal Artifactory repository which is configured with separate paths for libraries and plugins, release and snapshot versions. 
As an equivalent to `~/.m2/settings.xml` I used the following `~/.gradle/init.gradle` file:-

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/libs-releases" }
            maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshots" }
            maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/atlassian-cache" }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/plugins-releases" }
        maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/plugins-snapshots" }
        maven { url "https://internal.example.com/artifactory/atlassian-cache" }
    }
}
```

- the `buildscript` block refers to search locations for gradle plugins used by your build.
- the second `repositories` block refers to search locations for dependencies of your project.
- `mavenLocal()` refers to the local filesystem repo `~/.m2/repository`.

More info:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way for Gradle to set up mirrors to maven repositories is modifying the url in init.gradle or init.gradle.kts.

For example, I want to mirror mavenCentral() to 'https://mirrors.tencent.com/nexus/repository/maven-public/' and gradlePluginPortal() to 'https://mirrors.tencent.com/nexus/repository/gradle-plugins/', just place the code in `<UserDir>/.gradle/init.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
fun RepositoryHandler.enableMirror() {
    all {
        if (this is MavenArtifactRepository) {
            val originalUrl = this.url.toString().removeSuffix("/")
            urlMappings[originalUrl]?.let {
                logger.lifecycle("Repository[$url] is mirrored to $it")
                this.setUrl(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

val urlMappings = mapOf(
    "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" to "https://mirrors.tencent.com/nexus/repository/maven-public/",
    "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2" to "https://mirrors.tencent.com/nexus/repository/maven-public/",
    "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2" to "https://mirrors.tencent.com/nexus/repository/gradle-plugins/"
)

gradle.allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories.enableMirror()
    }
    repositories.enableMirror()
}

gradle.beforeSettings { 
    pluginManagement.repositories.enableMirror()
    dependencyResolutionManagement.repositories.enableMirror()
}
```

It will be loaded by every local project on your device. No more modification to the source code of the projects.